# How to remove a-tag's title param in tt_news using typoscript

Tags: hyperlink, typo3, typoscript, tt-news

The standard output of a tt_news list view hyperlink is like:

```
<a href="link-to-full-article" title="News Headline">News Headline</a>
```

How to remove the title tag from the standard output with typoscript ? So that you get:

```
<a href="link-to-full-article">News Headline</a>
```

I' am looking for a typoscript something like:

```
plugin.tt_news.displayList.linkParams.ATagParams >
```

Info: The template (sub)marker which includes the hyperlink is called:

```
<!-- ###LINK_ITEM### -->
   ... some Headline ...
<!-- ###LINK_ITEM### -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's

```
plugin.tt_news.displayList.linkTitleField =
```

However title will be there, it will not be filled.

If you want to remove the empty title part as well you need to dive into the plugin to remove it.

Comment: Seems to be the only typoscript that does what the question is looking for.

Comment: But it does not remove the title tag, it will be just empty. I think w3c validator will throw a warning or even an error at that point if sombody cares.

Answer (score 2):

There is a hook for this.

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['tt_news']['getSingleViewLinkHook']
```

You will have to use it in an own extension.

Your hook consuming class will have to implement the following method

```
function processSingleViewLink(&$linkWrap, $url, &$params, &$pObj) {

  // modify $linkWrap to remove title="" using regex
  [...]

}
```

See here for reference how to consume hooks in TYPO3: http://typo3.org/documentation/article/how-to-use-existing-hooks-in-your-own-extension/